# How to keep the hamburger icon in my flutter app after I go another stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a drawer and I can open it with the hamburger icon on top-left corner. If I change the screen to another page, this hamburger icon become a back button (<--). How to make this into a hamburger icon again? (So no back button but open the drawer on every screen)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Burger icon is from having a `Drawer` on your `Scaffold`.

If your next page/route has a `Scaffold` with a `drawer:` specified, you'll get the "burger" icon button again.

Without a `drawer:` specified on `Scaffold` Flutter will default to the back arrow to go to the previous route.

Here's an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DrawerDirectoryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Drawer Directories'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
            child: Text('Page One. Click to go to Page Two.'),
          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PageTwo())
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawerDirectory(),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Burger Time!'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Page TWO /flex'),
      ),
      drawer: MyDrawerDirectory(), // ← Drawer Directory a.k.a. burger icon
    );
  }
}

class MyDrawerDirectory extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          ListTile(title: Text('Page One'), onTap: () => _navPush(context, DrawerDirectoryPage())),
          ListTile(title: Text('Page Two'), onTap: () => _navPush(context, PageTwo()))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<dynamic> _navPush(BuildContext context, Widget page) {
    return Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => page,
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In App Bar of next page put

```
leading: BurgerIcon(),
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `automaticallyImplyLeading: false` in appBar of next page then set leading icon like this:

```
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  leading: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        } else {
          scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
        }
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.menu,
          size: 30,
          color: appColor,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

In the AppBar widget, you can specify a leading widget. After you specify a `leading` widget (in your case, an Icon Button), you should set AppBar's `automaticallyImplyLeading = false`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the methods `Navigator.of(context).push` or `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed` you will also experience this issue.

You can use other method to navigate between screens so it doesn't show the hamburger button